# WSO2 ApplicationServer-setup a cluster but Mgt Console getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: wso2

I followed the official guide to set up a cluster (Clustering AS 5.3.0)
(https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Setting+up+a+Cluster).

But eventually, I could not reach the management page with https://localhost:9443/carbon, and the browser redirect to https://localhost/carbon/admin/login.jsp, but getting"ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

[PRODUCT_HOME]/repository/conf/carbon.xml

```
<HostName>PCSKY01347</HostName>
<MgtHostName>PCSKY01347</MgtHostName>
```

[PRODUCT_HOME]/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml

```
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    port="9763"
    proxyPort="80"
    ...
    />
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    port="9443"
    proxyPort="443"
    ...
    />
```

NOTE: 
I do not setup the load balancer.
While server starting, I'm not getting any error message. And display member joined message in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'proxyPort' needs to be added in catalina-server.xml only if the fronted by a load balancer.
In this case, it is not required.
Therefore removing 'proxyPorts' should allow you to access the management console.

Comment: I can access management console now, but there's one thing still don't understand, I still not understand how to configure the hostName and MgtHostName in cluster envirnoment.

Manager Node (required to set the HostName and MgtHostName):
<HostName> XXX.XXX.XXX.XX1 </HostName>
<MgtHostName> XXX.XXX.XXX.XX1 </MgtHostName>

Worker Node-A(only set the HostName): 
<HostName> XXX.XXX.XXX.XX2 </HostName>

Worker Node-B(only set the HostName): 
<HostName> XXX.XXX.XXX.XX3 </HostName>
is It correct concept ?

Comment: You have to set the same `<HostName>` in all nodes within the cluster. 

`<HostName>` is used for service calls among nodes. 
`<MgtHostName>` is used to construct the the management console access URL. Management console access  is only required for the manager node. 
We do not access the management console of worker nodes. Therefore is not required to set the `<MgtHostName>` in worker nodes

Comment: thanks again, I suppose management console(Manager Node) can list out a set of application servers that I can manage together.  but, how to find out this function???